# Paginating a list of links in rails3 w/Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, will-paginate

Essential question:  how can I create a paginated list of ~1000 objects in Rails 3, while needing to create the link destination for each object in the list?

I'm working on a project with ~1000 users I'd like to display with pagination.  Site is made using Rails 3, and would like to use Bootstrap pagination display help if possible.

Here's the most relevant chunk of code, where I create the list and cycle through all users to add a link to their profile:

```
<ul class="list">   
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li style="list-style-type: none"><a href="/users/<%= user.id %>" class="user"><%= user.name %></a></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I was thinking of using the will_paginate-bootstrap gem, but I can't figure out how to implement it when I need to loop through @users to add a link for each one.  I'm relatively new to Rails, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in the Users controller, add the will_paginate code for getting a @user instance variable like this: `@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])`. Then in your view, add `<%= will_paginate @users, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails %>`. You can put this wherever you want the pagination to show up, so at the top or the bottom of the list, or even both if you want. Then somewhere on the page, put something like this, which will render the _user.html.erb partial for each user in the @users variable that was set in the controller earlier:

```
<ul class="list">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
```

In that _user.html.erb file, you can put whatever code you want to display with each user, such as a link to the user's show page `<%= link_to user.name, user, :class => "user" %>` or a user avatar.